# How come Legolas only runs out of arrows in The Battle of the Five Armies?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Legolas, the elf from Mirkwood, never runs out of arrows in any of the Lord of the Rings or Hobbit movies except the Battle of the Five Armies. How come that's the only one? How does Legolas always have an endless amount of arrows, except in that movie?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InfiniteSupplies

Comment: It was probably in the script.